# Error accessing Object Property "A field or property with the name {PROPERTY_NAME} was not found on the selected data source"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, properties

Having trouble with some code when moving it to a server. The code runs fine on my local machine. I have no problem accessing this property on my local machine. But, when I Upload it to my development server, I get this error:

> A field or property with the name 'CreatedBy.FullName' was not found on the selected data source.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: A field or property with the name 'CreatedBy.FullName' was not found on the selected data source.
>   Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): A field or property with the name 'CreatedBy.FullName' was not found on the selected data source.]
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField.GetValue(Control controlContainer) +1788095
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField.OnDataBindField(Object sender, EventArgs e) +67
>          System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +91
>          System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +92
>          System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +15
>          System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +201
>          System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +101
>          System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +15
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[] fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource) +166
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +3098
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +66
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +14
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) +128
>          System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +33
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +66
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +75
>          System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +102
>          System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
>          System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
>          System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
>          System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
>          System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
>          System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
>          System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
>          System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2496

Here is what the aspx page looks like (snip):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" DataKeyNames="ApplicationID" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="applicationID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Admin/ManageRoles.aspx?applicationID={0}" Text="View App Roles" />
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="applicationID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Admin/ManageApplicationUsers.aspx?applicationID={0}" Text="View App Users" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ApplicationID" HeaderText="ApplicationID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ApplicationID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedBy.FullName" HeaderText="Created By" SortExpression="CreatedByID" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedDate" HeaderText="CreatedDate" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CreatedDate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ModifiedBy.FullName" HeaderText="Modified By" SortExpression="ModifiedByID" NullDisplayText="&lt;i&gt;null&lt;/i&gt;" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ModifiedDate" HeaderText="ModifiedDate" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ModifiedDate" NullDisplayText="&lt;i&gt;null&lt;/i&gt;" />
        </Columns>
<!-- SNIP: styling -->
</asp:GridView>
```

---

**UPDATE**
I've got my code to run by using a workaround. If I use a template field instead of bound field, it will run. for example, I use this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CreatedBy.FullName") %>' TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CreatedBy.FullName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

instead of this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedBy.FullName" HeaderText="Created By" SortExpression="CreatedByID" ReadOnly="True" />
```

I'm glad it's working now, but frankly, I'd like to know what the problem was too!

Comment: Are you using Telerik, by chance?

Comment: Is the name for your `datasource` spelled correctly?  Are you pointed at the correct `datasource`?  As in, is your local 'datasource' the same as the one you are pointed at when you push your code?

Comment: I get the same problem. Was it because your datasource had the dot notation? (i.e. `DataField="CreatedBy.FullName"`)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is this:

A `BoundField` displays the information from your `datasource` as **text** and the `TemplateField` allows for a mixture of `HTML`, `WebControls` and also `data-binding` syntax.

Comment: I know what the different controls do. What I don't understand is why it was working on my local machine with bound fields, but would not work on server as bound fields (that is why I switched them to template fields). As you can see, my templates are just text only, so I feel that I should be able to use bound field, and it works on my local, but not on server.

Comment: I would have to agree since your templates are just text.  But, I don't know that I could even hazard a guess as to why it worked locally vs. on the server without first seeing some code.